# AngularJS Bootstrap dialog to grow with content up to a max height

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap 2.3.2. Right now, it appears bootstrap has a max-height set to 400px. I'd like to allow the content of the dialog to stretch the dialog up to 90% of the window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bootstrap, I like to overwrite some of it with my own CSS. So I would find the CSS selector in the bootstrap.css file that sets the max-height to 400px. Then use that same selector in your own stylesheet (linked below the bootstrap css so that it overwrites it) to set the max-height to 90%.

Edit: the css selector you're looking for is

```
.modal-body {}
```

Comment: I don't want it to always be 90%, I want it to grow with the content _up to_ 90%.

Comment: Oh then you would change the max-height attribute.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since in the end I did have to change the max-height attribute, but I had to set it with JavaScript. I could not find a pure CSS solution. A percentage can only be used on max-height if the container's height is explicitly set and I wouldn't know that value ahead of time. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height under "Percentages". I had to use JavaScript to calculate the height I wanted instead.

Comment: Technically it is best practice to write your css in a different file to override bootstrap instead of modifying bootstrap directly. Otherwise, changes to the bootstrap files could be hard to track, especially for new developers to the project and especially in the event the project updates bootstrap. Indeed, it may cause a veritable shitstorm when no one can figure out why styles changed.